# How to search for ID number in java?

Tags: java

My problem is I need to make a program where you can search for an employee based on their ID number. Which needs to be something like "E1" or "E2". I am struggling to find a way to search for numbers and letters in the same object. It only works when I use just a number like 1 or 2 by using Int.

How can I store both a letter and integer in an object? Is there something similar to String that stores letters or Int that stores numbers but for both letters and numbers?

Ex. I can search for my employe already but their ID is currently just "1" or "2" or "3". I need to change it to "E1" or "E2" etc. But it wont work with String or Int.

I am searching an array. In an employee class

Comment: Where are you searching? In a java object you already have? A file? A database? The internet? Please clarify.

Comment: Elaborate your question with an example then only we will be able to help you.

Comment: Im searching an array.

Comment: an array of what? Please give us the Class

Comment: You need to include sample code for what you are trying to do.  The simple answer is that you have a String[] so you use the equals() method to comparison elements of that array against the value sought.  But then what..

Comment: I´ve already done that my program is working if your searching for an intager BUT I need to change it so u can search for ex E1 instead of just 1

Comment: My code is in Swedish probably won´t make any sense to you

Comment: You have to use a Collections (Map) where you can use E1, E2 as key and details as value.

Comment: will that work in an array?

Comment: Java is Java - variable/class names in Swedish won't matter.

Comment: Collections are not an array, these are the interface that implements a class. Using key you can perform search operations.

Comment: If your IDs are Strings, you can compare elements with `String1.equals(String2)`.

Comment: I know Swedish, bring on the code

Answer (score 1):

You can check, if two Strings are equal, by using the `equals` method: `String1.equals(String2);`

Also, you could implement a new class implementing the interface [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). In this class you could split the ID into a String and an Integer part:

```
public class EmployeeID implements Comparable {
    String s = null;
    Integer i = null;

    public EmployeeID(String s, Integer i) {
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void equals(EmployeeID id) {
        return new String(s + i).equals(new String(id.s + id.i));
    }

    @Override
    public void compareTo(EmployeeID id) {
        return new String(s + i).compareTo(new String(id.s + id.i));
    }
}
```

Of course, if you do not need to compare elements (which can be useful for sorting), you can just implement this wrapper class without the comparable interface.
The `equals` method compares two ids and is not implemented in the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, but the [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class, which is the superclass of every class.

Answer (score 0):

No code provided so I'm guessing as to what you actually are trying to do.

```
public class SomeIds {
  private String[] ids;

  public boolean isPresent(String id) {
    for (String element : ids) {
      if (element.equals(id)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * returns the index of the first element matching the id 
   * provided or -1 if it is not found
   */
  public int indexOf(String id) {
    for (int index = 0 ; index < ids.length ; ++index) {
      if (ids[index].equals(id)) {
        return index;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to mix types (i.e. numbers and letters). You'll have to use a `String` for storage of the ID, in which case, you can use [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) to search:

```
String searchTerm = "E1";

for (Employee employe : employeeArr) {
    if (employe.getId() == searchTerm) {
         System.out.println("Employe_ID: E" + employe.getEmployeId() + 
            "\narbetstitel: " + employe.getArbetsTitel());       
    }
}
```

Better yet, use a `HashMap` so you don't have to loop to find an employee:

```
HashMap<String, Employee> employees = new HashMap<>(); // String to store IDs

Employee e = new Employee();
employees.put("E1", e);

// To fetch an employee
Employee e1 = employees.get("E1");
if (e1 != null) {
    System.out.println("Employe_ID: E" + e1.getEmployeId() + 
        "\narbetstitel: " + e1.getArbetsTitel());
}
```